# Why doesn't the div show when the url changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, relative-path, relative-url

I'm trying to get certain `<div>`s to show up when the url has a certain hash. So far, it works when I am navigating from a different page but doesn't work when I click from the same page.

Example: If I am on the page1 and click to go to `/page2#hash1` then `div1` linked to hash1 will show up on page2 (all the `<div>`'s are initially hidden). But if the url is currently `/page2#hash1` and I want to jump to `#hash2` on the same page, the url will change to `/page2#hash2` but `div2` will not show up and `div1` won't go away.

Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('#hash1') > -1){
    $('.div1').slideToggle();
} else if(window.location.href.indexOf('#hash2') > -1 ) {
    $('.div2').slideToggle();
}
```

Comment: On which event are you running this code?  The window onload event is not fired when the hash changes IIRC.  You might need to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers.onhashchange to listen for hash change events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the onhashchange event to trigger your function

```
window.onhashchange  = function(){
  if (window.location.href.indexOf('#hash1') > -1){
            $('.div1').slideToggle();
        }
        else if(window.location.href.indexOf('#hash2') > -1 ) {
            $('.div2').slideToggle();
        }

}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whwgtt9y/) care of @HaukurHaf